# Prevent keyboard for hidding view android

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-edittext

I've already made a good search on this but i never find a working solution so that's why i post here.

I have an android application where there is a TableLayout with some View in it (EditText, TextView and CheckBox).

I implemented my own keyboard so i can control the information entered by the user.

My TableLayout is in a ScrollView because the TableLayout can have many lines.

The problem i have is when my keyboard showes up, it hides the EditText focused. Usually android push the EditText up to make it visible but not in my case. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add the attribute `windowSoftInputMode` to your manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

within the `<activity>` tag.

Comment: Hello TronicZornB, yes i tried it and it doesn't work for me :/

Comment: Do you think the problem is that my keyboard is too big so android doesn't know how to handle that ? Because my keyboard is like 1 and half time bigger that the android text keyboard for example

Comment: @Tristan it was odd but what actually worked for me was using `adjustUnspecified`. Have you tried that one?

Comment: actually it works with adjustPan but just with native android keyboard not with my custom keyboard.

Comment: @Tristan hmm... ok. That it seems that it is something with your custom keyboard. I don't know about making custom keyboards, but is there an attribute that you can add to it so that it will behave the same as the stock keyboard when it comes to this situation? Maybe look further into that as an option.

Comment: Thank you for your help @TronicZomB. I'm looking at the native KeyboardView class in the android sdk maybee i'll find the solution in it. If yes i'll post for other!

Comment: @Tristan Sounds great. Glad I could try to help some :)

Answer (score 0):

always have the same problem. I find out that the windowsSoftInputMode="adjustPan" or others options doesn't work with custom keyboard.

My CustomKeyboard is a class that implements a KeyboardView, link an xml to this keyboardView and has 2 methods to show or hide it...

If someone has a idea why the adjustPan doesn't work with custom keyboards, please let met know!

Tristan

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with custom keyboard using KeyboardView and I solved it by setting item selection with short delay.

```
public boolean isCustomKeyboardVisible() {
return keyboardView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}

public void showCustomKeyboard() {
    if (!isCustomKeyboardVisible()) {
    keyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Calling my custom listener
    onKeyboardVisibilityChanged.visibilityChanged(true); 
    listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listView.setSelection(position);
        }
    }, 50);
}
}

public void hideCustomKeyboard() {
if (isCustomKeyboardVisible()) {
    keyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    onKeyboardVisibilityChanged.visibilityChanged(false);
}
}
```